# Как записать в файл одну строку, после окончание строки переходил на след. строку

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

Имеется скрипт на php, для записи данных из mysql в csv.
В первую строку записывается заголовок.
Затем идет запись основной информации.
Проблема заключается в том что первоя строка записывается и сразу следом идет основная часть. Не идет переход на новую строку.

```
  $code_group = $_GET['code_group'];

// подключение к базе данных
include("db.php");

$csv_file = ''; // создаем переменную, в которую записываем строки

$sql_query = "SELECT `l_surname`, `l_name`, `l_patronymic`, `l_mail` FROM `temp_listener` where `code_group` = '$code_group'";
$result = mysql_query($sql_query, $db);
if ($result)
{
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
      $csv_file .= '"'.$row["l_surname"].'";"'.$row["l_name"].'";"'.$row["l_patronymic"].'";"'.$row["l_mail"].'"'."\r\n";
      // в качестве начала и конца полей я указал " (двойные кавычки)
      // в качестве разделителей полей я указал , (запятая)
      // \r\n - это перенос строки
   }
}
$csv_file2 = '1;2;3;4;\r\n';

$file_name = 'for_portal.csv'; // название файла
$file = fopen($file_name,"w"); // открываем файл для записи, если его нет, то создаем его в текущей папке, где расположен скрипт
fwrite($file,trim($csv_file2)); // записываем в файл строки
fwrite($file,trim($csv_file)); // записываем в файл строки
fclose($file); // закрываем файл

// задаем заголовки. то есть задаем всплывающее окошко, которое позволяет нам сохранить файл.
header('Content-type: application/csv'); // указываем, что это csv документ
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$file_name); // указываем файл, с которым будем работать
readfile($file_name); // считываем файл
unlink($file_name); // удаляем файл. то есть когда вы сохраните файл на локальном компе, то после он удалится с сервера
```

Comment: Как выглядит в текстовом файле? Предполагаю, вы с неправильными опциями открываете CSV файл.

Answer (score 1):

Как создать csv и не изобрести велосипед. Обращаемся к офф документации по ссылке http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fputcsv.php
есть функция `fputcsv()` специально для создания csv файла.

```
<?php

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

помойму выглядит куда лучше чем ваш вариант.
пример из вашего кода это буде что то подобное

```
<?php
$code_group = $_GET['code_group'];

// подключение к базе данных
include("db.php");

$sql_query = "SELECT `l_surname`, `l_name`, `l_patronymic`, `l_mail` FROM `temp_listener` where `code_group` = '$code_group'";
$result = mysql_query($sql_query, $db);
$csvArray = array()
if ($result)
{
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
      $csvArray[] = array (
         $row["l_surname"],
         $row["l_name"],
         $row["l_patronymic"],
         $row["l_mail"]
      );
   }
}

$csvArray[] = array (1,2,3,4);

$file_name = 'for_portal.csv'; // название файла
$csvFile = fopen($file_name,"w");
foreach($csvArray as $field) {
    fputcsv($csvFile,$fields);
}

fclose($file); // закрываем файл

header('Content-type: application/csv'); 
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$file_name);
readfile($file_name); 
unlink($file_name); 

?>
```

вроде красивей смотриться. 
П.С. Прекратите использовать mysql_ расширение
П.П.С. перенос строки \n\r запишиться как \n\r в фаил если обрамлен '' ординарными ковычками.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но ваш код не работает. Пишет Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in www\reg\portal.php on line 15 на 15 линии находится if ($result) а до него $csvArray = array() я думал из-за того что не поставили кавычки. Но все равно выходит ошибка. Файл csv скачивается а внутри файла пишется <b>Warning</b>:  fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in <b>www\reg\portal.php</b> on line <b>33</b><br />

Comment: Решил сделать таким способом `$csv_file = ''; 
$csv_file .= 'LAST_NAME;NAME;SECOND_NAME;LOGIN;EMAIL;PASSWORD'."\r\n";
$sql_query = "SELECT `l_surname`, `l_name`, `l_patronymic`, `l_mail` FROM `temp_listener` where `code_group` = '$code_group'";
$result_sql = mysql_query($sql_query, $db);
if ($result_sql)
{
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_sql))
   {
      $csv_file .= ''.$row["l_surname"].';'.$row["l_name"].';'.$row["l_patronymic"].';'.$row["l_mail"].';'.$row["l_mail"].';123456'."\r\n";
 `
локально (на денвере) все работает, а на боевом сервере нет, только скачивается пустой csv файл

Comment: У вас в mysql есть данные @temaror